# Unable to update gems on production server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Can not update gems on production server.

I've tried `bundle install --deployment` and `bundle install --without development test`

But keep getting:

```
You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

If this is a development machine, remove the Gemfile freeze 
by running `bundle install --no-deployment
```

### EDIT

I don't know if this is correct, but needed a quick fix.  I ran `bundle install --no-deployment` then `bundle update` then ran `bundle install --deployment` again

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The instructions are probably a bit confusing. It's saying that you've modified your `Gemfile` on your development machine and just pushed those changes rather than running `bundle install` BEFORE committing the changes.

By running `bundle install` you will update your `Gemfile.lock` file. This should be pushed to your server as it's more important than `Gemfile`. Consider the `Gemfile` the plans for the `Gemfile.lock` file.

Always remember to:

1. Run `bundle install` if you change your `Gemfile`, even just to make sure. If it's too slow, pass `--local` through which forces it to only use local gems to resolve its dependencies.
2. Commit *both* the `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` file to your repository
3. Deploy both the `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` to your production servers to ensure that they're running the exact same dependencies as your development environment.

---

Running `bundle update` by itself can be construed as dangerous that will update *all* the dependencies of your application. It's mainly dangerous if you don't have solid version numbers specified in the `Gemfile`. I [wrote about it here.](http://ryanbigg.com/2011/01/why-you-should-run-bundle-update/)

Comment: OK, I think its starting to make sense. I did skip Gemfile.lock thinking that since server was production i should rely on that more.  So my mistake was not uploading the gemfile.lock?  Fortunately, I'm early in the game if I have to rebuild server.

Comment: I'm getting the same error though my `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` is in sync. I have even tried to delete the `Gemfile.lock` and regenerate it by running `bundle install`. But the new `Gemfile.lock` is identical bit for bit.

Comment: You might have changed Gemfile without triggering a change in Gemfile.lock. This happened to me when I moved something between the test and development groups. I ended up having to make a change that did trigger a Gemfile.lock change to get them back in sync (from bundler's perspective).

Answer (score 9):

FWIW I had this problem and fixed it by removing some conditional statements from my Gemfile (conditionals on OS) and rerunning bundle.

Comment: My comment to Ryan's answer above may be related.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `conditional statements`

Answer (score 7):

FYI: You can also get this error if you use source blocks like this:

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-jquery'
end
```

You'll see an exclamation point in the Gemfile.lock for this gem:

```
  rails-assets-jquery!
```

Just define the additional source normally, i.e.

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org'
gem 'rails-assets-jquery'
```

(BTW cf. [here](http://bundler.io/blog/2014/08/14/bundler-may-install-gems-from-a-different-source-than-expected-cve-2013-0334.html) about using multiple gem sources.)

Comment: According to the mentioned article using the non-block version of `source` is unsafe. Is there a way to use the block version?

Comment: @Besi I do not know, but Bundler should issue a warning. When it does, I plan to add the explicit :source option on the gem in question.

Comment: If you are reading this and wondering what's going on. My production server system ruby is still 1.9.3 with an outdated `bundler` version. When using `source` as a block, or a key on the gem, I got this error. By defining it as an additional source, I got rid of the exclamation point as mentioned by Jim Flood, and the deployment succeeded. I'm assuming older versions of bundler simply can't handle the source block, or source hash notation.

Comment: Another (probably better) way to resolve this problem with `source` blocks is to ensure that your bundler versions are in sync between dev/prod servers.  I had this problem while running bundler 1.7.7 on a dev box, and 1.7.1 on a production server.  Updating both to 1.10.4 resolved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

This can be caused by an old version of the bundler gem on the server you're deploying to (in this case production). Logging into the server and running a `gem update bundler` resolved the issue for me. The server I was deploying to was running version 1.7.4 and the current version was 1.9.

Comment: The only thing that's worked for me. I was already removed the `Gemfile.lock` and generate it again but in the server still keeping the old version. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue with my production server still using an old version of a gem, even though the Gemfile.lock showed the correct, updated version. My production server was running on Unicorn - and shutting down / starting it back up again fixed the issue - instead of sending the HUP signal, which did jack all to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. Was exactly what my problem was too.

Comment: Wow. I spent the last error trying down the same situation as yours (old gem). I wish I would have tried this earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

bundle install failed on my "development" machine because of the mysql-gem on osx...

I also needed a quick fix. So I cloned the repo to a new folder on the production machine, ran "bundle install" there and committed the Gemfile.lock to the repo.

Comment: It's stuff like this that makes me really hate bundler

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem (Ubuntu 12.10 & 12.04, one of which behind a proxy server).
My problem was that I had some `git://` protocols in the Gemfile. Changing this to `http://` helped me get it all working.