# capistrano deployment error after Bundler upgrade and adding source block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, bundler, rvm-capistrano

The latest branch of my project includes changes to the Gemfile based on the upgrade to Bundler 1.10.5, notably the use of a source block for two internal gems. This appears to be the cause of a problem when attempting to deploy to the testing server, where capistrano throws an error and rolls back the deploy.

Command generating errors:

```
bundle install --gemfile /path/to/Gemfile --path /path/to/shared/bundle --deployment --without development test
```

Error message (private data anonymized but otherwise as in the original):

```
You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

You have deleted from the Gemfile:
* internal_gem1 (= 0.1.11)
* internal_gem2 (= 0.0.6)

You have changed in the Gemfile:
* internal_gem1 from `no specified source` to `rubygems repository

http://rubygems.org/, https://REDACTED@gem.fury.io/me/`
* internal_gem2 from `no specified source` to `rubygems repository
http://rubygems.org/, https://REDACTED@gem.fury.io/me/`
```

`Gemfile` contains lines:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
source 'https://REDACTED@gem.fury.io/me/' do
  gem 'internal_gem1', '0.1.11' #, :path => '/path/to/gem/optional'
  gem 'internal_gem2', '0.0.6'
end

gem "bundler", "~> 1.7"
... 
# more gems and some groups follow
...

BUNDLED WITH
   1.10.5
```

Based on common sense and a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29042856/611068), I tried running `gem install bundler -v '1.10.5'` on the testing server, and it appears to have installed (installation messages showed success and `gem which bundler` returns a path containing the new version number), but there was no change in the deployment error.

Both `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` are tracked in git and get deployed to the server (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6785750/611068)). There is no `vendor/cache` directory present (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12353214/611068)). Everything works smoothly locally, and deployment of a branch without the source block in the Gemfile went smoothly just a few hours ago. How can I fix this Bundler deployment problem?

Comment: It is possible that you have updated `bundler` on your CI server but not your app server. I also ran into the same issue and tried the same fix. When I ssh-ed into the app box, I discovered the version of `bundler` was ancient, which was what our capistrano job was using during deployment.